# Using /effect on people with a certain amount of points on a scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am trying to make a double jump for my server and i want to give people the jump boost effect when their score on the objective "Jumping?" is 1. I tried
/effect @a[score_Jumping?=1] 8 3 10 but that didn't work. Please help!

Comment: try removing the ?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, try removing the '?'.

But your real problem is `score_Jumping=1`, use `score_Jumping_min=1` to check for a minimum score.

Because `score_jumping=` checks for a maximum and is actually "`score_jumping_max=`".

Comment: @FireGuardian If that worked, please consider checking the answer as correct